# Memsql: how to use load command or loader to load TPCH data

Tags: singlestore

I have data generated for region table is below format.

```
    0|AFRICA|lar deposits. blithely final packages cajole. regular waters are final requests. regular accounts are according to |
    1|AMERICA|hs use ironic, even requests. s |
    2|ASIA|ges. thinly even pinto beans ca |
    3|EUROPE|ly final courts cajole furiously final excuse |
    4|MIDDLE EAST|uickly special accounts cajole carefully blithely close requests. carefully final asymptotes haggle furiousl |
```

I tried several versions of load command to load above data in region table

```
    CREATE REFERENCE TABLE REGION (" +
    "R_REGIONKEY  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
    "R_NAME       CHAR(25) NOT NULL," +
    "R_COMMENT    VARCHAR(152))

    1. stmt.execute(s"load data infile \'$filename\' into table REGION COLUMNS TERMINATED BY \'|\'");
    2. stmt.execute(s"load data infile \'$filename\' into table REGION FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'|\'");
    3. stmt.execute(s"load data infile \'$filename\' into table REGION COLUMNS TERMINATED BY \'|\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'");
   4.stmt.execute(s"load data infile \'$filename\' into table REGION FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'|\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'|\'");
```

But no success. Help me to format proper load command to load data in given format. Also let me know how can I achieve same using Memsql loader utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output format from dbgen should be loaded with `fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '|\n'`